# Android Notification Issue: Notification Canceled Without Displaying, No Error Messages

Tags: java, android

Am trying to initiate notification functionality in my app, the problem is that its not showing or giving any serious error to guide if theys a problem in my configuration or not, am using a min sdk version 26 to target sdk 33 which requires firstly to create a notification channel with a specific ID, my notification is still not popping on my notification bar and using an android 10 phone to test the functionality, below is the Notification code i initiated in my activity.

```
 CharSequence name = "My Upload";
        String description = "Upload confirmation to firestore";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(Constants.CHANNEL_UPLOAD_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        channel.enableVibration (true);

        // Register the channel with the system
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
```

And here is the code for the actual Notification am trying to initiate which is being conducted in a fragment, the fragment is from the same Activity i created a channel

private void sendNotification() {

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(requireActivity (), Constants.CHANNEL_UPLOAD_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Testing")
            .setContentText("Its working")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_official_nichx_logo)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setAutoCancel(true);// Replace with your desired icon
    int notificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

    NotificationManagerCompat manager= NotificationManagerCompat.from (requireActivity ());

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=33) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission (requireActivity (), Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
    }

    manager.notify (1,notification.build ());
    
}
```

And this the response am getting from logcat

```
2024-01-01 02:25:11.910 1081-3658/? E/NotificationService: No vibration for canceled notification : 0|com.adsilk.nichx|1|null|10171
```

it seems like it cancels before it even shows, what may be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add the following code before your last line `manager.notify (1,notification.build ());`, then your code works for me:

```java
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    return;
}
```

Without these lines, I have an error message, that the permission test is missing...

Comment: The Shortcome of that approach is that when I run my app,it checks for permission and by default it's denied..that means it will always return false for Post notification, Post Notification permission has been introduced in api 33 and possibly for upcoming new ones and am currently working within api 26 and 33 so those below don't necessarily need the permission for notifications ,I feel this is actually close to the solution because api 33 is included and I would have to write the code in a way to check and I don't know if u can help further

Comment: A few clarifications to my answer. I copied your code _unchanged_ into `Android Studio Hedgehog` with `compileSdk = targetSdk = 34, minSdk = 28`. Android Studio complained and itself suggested the 3 required lines listed in my reply to be add. The compiled completed code then ran e.g. on a phone with Android 10/API 29. There was _no_ dialog window where you had to give any permission (it _isn't_ denied by default as you think). There is _no_ necessary  permission line in the `Manifest`. Try it out!

Comment: Thanks very much,let me try it out again

Comment: I  have updated the code ,you can equally check but still its not executing a notification @Cloverleaf

Comment: I am still successful. So
1. have you debugged your code step by step? Did you get to the _last_ line? Were the arguments as you expected?
2. have you perhaps unintentionally switched off the notifications for this app? (On the _smartphone_: ⚙ -> Apps -> (your App) -> Notification)
3. write a _new_ app from scratch (like me) and test it. If you see the notification, the problem is in the part of your code of your original app, which you haven't shown us.

Comment: For number 2,I never touched the app notification settings ..the channel is being created successfully which I tested...for 3 I will do so and give you a feedback, infact let me try to raise the SDK to 34 as yours just to see if it will have any effect and let me try to update the dependencies just to see....I will have to recheck my code but as for the code for creating the channel is ok because it does create it,the issue is having the notification to show

Comment: its safe to say that my notifications are now showing,thanks for your help....happy coding